# Symfony2 Sonata admin bundle: Non CRUD page

Tags: sonata-admin

I have setup a symfony2 project with sonata admin bundle.
it works fine. I can generate listviews and detail form for each entity.
But i want to create a new menu entry in left admin menu.
This new entry is not linked to an entity.

I just want to show a textarea and store result in a file (for testing first).
Do you know I what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In the sonata_admin section of your config, under the dashboard section you can see your groups, which are displayed in the left site navigation. There you can add a item, which links to your own, custom service.

Visit https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html to see how you can create your own admin service.